# Switching between tabs in Excel spreadsheet by using Dropbox / Combo Box and Macro

Tags: excel, vba, tabs, macros, switch-statement

i have been struggling with it for hours and I would like to ask you for the help, what VBA code and how should I implement this as I have around 30 tabs and I would like to create kind of a drop list in order to simplify switching between the tabs.

See below image:

[image]

Comment: We all love simple things. :) But you need to provide more details.

Comment: you could also build a Table of Contents tab with Hyperlinks to all the other tabs and a Hyperlink back to the ToC on each tab.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a validation listbox rather than a combo box then naming the cell "wsSelect" for example as this is simpler. Open Visual Basic and the sheet containing the list where the user is selecting the sheet to open and create a Worksheet Change sub using the two drop down boxes at the top of the code box. Then the following code will run the sub to change the worksheet when the list box value changes:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("wsSelect")) Is Nothing Then
    Call Pb_Switch_Sheet
End If
```

End Sub

You need to create a new module with a public sub in it to switch the sheet (excel doesn't like referring to different sheets in the module for a sheet). Then a simple sub like this should do the trick:

```
Public Sub Pb_Switch_Sheet()

Dim wsName As String
ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("wsSelect").Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws).Select
```

End Sub

Hope that helps!

A

Answer (score 0):

Try adding sheet names to the a combo box:

```
With Sheets(1)
    For shtIndex = 2 to Application.Sheets.Count
        .Combobox1.additem Sheets(shtIndex).name
    next shtIndex
end with
```

Run the below under the combobox1 change or click event

```
Sheets(combobox1.text).select
```